# Trying to use Amazon ElasticCache Redis Cluster on Laravel-4.2

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, laravel-4.2

With the following parameters I get the Predis ServerException MOVED 16353 x.x.x.x:6379.  The amazon Elasticache for redis has cluster mode enabled and 2 nodes. Can anyone advise on the correct configuration for this?

```
'redis' => [
           'cluster' => true,
           'default' => [
               'host' =>  'xxx.cache.amazonaws.com',
               'port' =>  6379,
               'database' => 0,
           ],

       ],
```